# brunch: Cannot find module "initialize" from "/"

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, coffeescript, brunch

I am desparating with brunch/node.js.
I have a project with a few simple pages, using brunch, backbone.js, jade, and coffeescript.

app/assets/index.html has the following scripts included:

```
<script src="data/vendor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="data/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="data/data.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">require('initialize');</script>
```

brunch-config.coffee:

```
exports.config =
  files:
    javascripts:
      defaultExtension: 'coffee'
      joinTo:
        'data/app.js': /^app/
        'data/vendor.js': /^vendor/
      order:
        before: [
          'vendor/scripts/jquery-1.11.1.js',
          'vendor/scripts/underscore.js',
          'vendor/scripts/backbone-1.1.2-full.js',
        ]
  stylesheets:
    joinTo:
      'data/app.css': /^app\/styles/
  templates:
    defaultExtension: 'jade',
    joinTo:
      'data/app.js': /^app\/templates/
```

All the coffee files are compiled correctly and merged into *vendor.js* and *app.js*, and I can find the (javascript'ed) *initialize.coffee* code with grep in *app.js*.
app/initialize.coffee:

```
# The function called from index.html
$(document).ready ->
  app = require('application')
  app.initialize()
  return
```

I modelled this after the spa-bookmarks tutorial. But When I launch the brunch server, my Js browser console always tells me:

```
TypeError: _ is undefined
Error: Cannot find module "./initialize" from "/"
```

The TypeError doesn't bother me by now. But I can't find out *why the heck* the *initialize* module is not called.

I must admit that I am very new to Js and node.js, and have not fully understood (better: have no clue of) the way Js modules are bundled together and called.

I tried many possible variations, but did not get more out of it than this error message.
Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AAARRGH. Nearly each time I ask a question here after days of work and struggle, 5 minutes later I find the answer myself.

Problem was:
I configured brunch to look for the vendor js files in `/^vendor/`, but they were in *app/vendor*. Copied the folder to .. and everything worked.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience!  Would you please mark this answer as accepted?  Much appreciated!